# using jqgrid style for usual Table in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, coding-style

I'd prefer using Table and td instead of JqGrid but i like JqGrid styles.

has anyone used jqgrid style for usual Grid of asp.net MVC(i mean Table and td) before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [tableToGrid](http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/_2h30t8wte.htm) plugin to apply jqGrid styling and features to a regular table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we use it for [the paging and sorting](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/04/14/38200/)